# Привести строку в соответствие маске

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, можно ли регулярным выражением привести строку к нужному виду?

```
.a.b..c.d.
```

Причем, точек между элементами может быть сколько угодно. Строка должна стать такой:

```
a.b.c.d
```

Comment: конечно, можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let src = '.a.b..c.d.';

// split/join с фильтрацией
console.log(src.split(/\.+/).filter(a=>a).join('.'));

// replace(regexp), очищаем начало и конец, отдельно убираем дубликаты в середине.
console.log(src.replace(/^\.+|\.+$/g, '').replace(/\.+/g, '.'));

// match/join
console.log(src.match(/[^.]+/g).join('.'));
```